# VBA If cell (or range) on sheet1 contains any value then clear content of cell range on sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to achieve something which would be quite simple for you guys but proving a bit difficult for myself as beginner.

I am try to create script for following example:

"If Cells A1:A4 on sheet1 contain ANY value (text or int) then clear A1:A4 on sheet2"

I tried to construct few scripts but all failed.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Clear()
 If Not IsEmpty("A1") And Not IsEmpty("A2") And Not IsEmpty("A3") And Not IsEmpty("A4") Then
    Range("A1:A4").Clear
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub ClearCell()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4")
        If r.Value <> "" Then Sheets("Sheet2").Range(r.Address).Clear
    Next r
End Sub
```

*This assumes you need the check to be cell-by-cell.*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner, the cell value is counted when it is an Empty String.

```
    Public Sub ClearRange()
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("a1:a4"), "<>") > 0 Then Range("a1:a4").ClearContents
    End Sub
```